# SQL - Get all posts which are not voted by current user

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 MySQL tables, namely `posts` and `votes`
The **posts** table contains articles published by authors (users).
The **votes** table contains votes against the particular *post* by users.

I'd like to get **all posts** that *have* or *haven't* been *voted* on by the **current user**.

What MySQL statement should I write to achieve the desired result?

*Table 1* **posts** contains 4 columns.
`post_id` is the primary key, and `author_id` stores `user_id` from **user** table.

| post_id (int-11) | title (text) | author_id (int-11) | created (datetime) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This is 1st Post | 2 | 2023-02-24 14:43:49 |
| 2 | This is 2nd Post | 5 | 2023-02-26 18:16:17 |
| 3 | This is 3rd Post | 1 | 2023-03-01 05:42:51 |
| 4 | This is 4th Post | 2 | 2023-03-01 08:20:15 |
| 5 | This is 5th Post | 8 | 2023-03-02 12:35:49 |

*Table 2* **votes** contains 4 columns.
`vote_id` is the primary key, and `post_id` & `author_id` store values from the foreign tables, namely **post** and **user**. `vote` column can store **enum('approve', 'reject')**

| vote_id (int-11) | post_id (int-11) | user_id (int-11) | vote enum('approve', 'reject') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | approve |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | reject |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | reject |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | approve |

How to get all post rows that are not voted on by the current user or voted by the current user. (both condition seperately)

Also, how do I get the number of votes for a particular post in the same SQL statement?

**Desired Result** *(Not Voted)* 
`user_id = 3` is the *current user*. 
`user_id = 3` has already voted for `post_id 2 & 3`. 
Except for *post_id = 2 & 3,* all rows should be returned.

| post_id (int-11) | title (text) | author_id (int-11) | created (datetime) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This is 1st Post | 2 | 2023-02-24 14:43:49 |
| 4 | This is 4th Post | 2 | 2023-03-01 08:20:15 |
| 5 | This is 5th Post | 8 | 2023-03-02 12:35:49 |

I tried this **SQL** to fetch all rows for which the current user (3) has votes, but it is showing all rows.

```
SELECT p.*, v.*
FROM `posts` p
LEFT JOIN `votes` v ON p.post_id = v.post_id 
LEFT JOIN `votes` v2 on p.post_id = v2.post_id and v2.user_id='3';
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM `posts` p
LEFT JOIN `votes` v ON p.post_id = v.post_id 
WHERE v.user_id = 3
```

and `WHERE v.user_id <> 3`
for teh other case.
If I understood correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Zeljko, for the help.
It worked.

Jonathan200, in another answer, gives the solution of using a sub-query that also worked.

Sub-Query or Join, which is better and more optimised? Which one should I use?

Comment: For such a simple query I do not think it is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of you have tried: The current user filter is part of left outer join.

To get the result you want, you can use NOT [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator and post_id from votes to buid your [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e3369/2):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE post_id NOT IN (
     SELECT post_id
     FROM votes
     where user_id = '3' 
)
```

| post_id | title | author_id | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This is 1st Post | 2 | 2023-02-24T14:43:49Z |
| 4 | This is 4th Post | 2 | 2023-03-01T08:20:15Z |
| 5 | This is 5th Post | 8 | 2023-03-02T12:35:49Z |

Comment: Thanks Jonathan
I didn't even try the sub-query; I'm glad you answered in this manner as well.

Sub-Query or join, which is faster?

Comment: Hi @manasGain, in most DB engines, IN subquery will convert to join-like operation in query planning stage, but with in IN operator, you don't need to worry about  possible duplicated post_id in votes table. the in operator will handle possible duplication post_id implictly. If you do run into isseus on performance with your specific DB engine, you can explictly rewrite the query in join fashion, but you do need to handle possible duplication specifically in the query.